# How to get root word of a given word in lex

Tags: lex

how can we find out the root word of a given word in lex? for example: when we the word that is given as input is decided the output should be "the root word is decide"

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
[a-zA-Z]*"ed"|[a-zA-Z]*"ly" {printf("the root word is %s",yytext);}
%%
main()
{
yyin=fopen("a.c","r");
yylex();
}
```

This code actually prints the given word. But i want the output as the root word without the ed or ly.

Answer (score 1):

If all your suffixes are the same length, there is no problem; you just need to decrease the length of the token. For example:

```
[a-zA-Z]*("ed"|"ly") { printf("the root word is %.*s",
                              yyleng-2, yytext);
                     }
```

Or, to store the result somewhere

```
[a-zA-Z]*("ed"|"ly") { sval = strndup(yytext, yyleng-2); }
```

In general, though, you might have suffixes of different lengths. In that case, one solution is to separate the rules:

```
[a-zA-Z]*("ed"|"ly") { sval = strndup(yytext, yyleng-2); }
[a-zA-Z]*"ing"       { sval = strndup(yytext, yyleng-3); }
```

You could refactor the action into a function which takes the suffix length as an argument (or a substitution pattern, see below.)

---

In English (as in most languages), you cannot actually just delete suffixes and get the root: ⇒

```
dotted ⇒ dot 
darted ⇒ dart
dated  ⇒ date
dried  ⇒ dry
```

So you probably don't want to just delete the suffix; you may want to delete more (as in `dotted`) or less (as in `dated`), or even delete and modify (as in `dried`). Even then, you will need a dictionary of exceptions. Flex may or may not be the best tool for this job.